# UIAlertView Button Event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uialertview

I have a question on Xamarin.Forms, I'm trying to navigate back page from detail page when UIAlertView pressed OK. But I couldn't do it. Here is my code;

```
{
    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView();
    alert.Title = "Warning";
    alert.AddButton("OK");
    alert.Message = "Payment not found!";
    alert.Clicked += ButtonClicked;
    alert.Show();
    return paymentList;
 }

 private void ButtonClicked(object sender, UIButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     //???
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is Xamarin.iOS and not Xamarin.Forms, can you explain what this has got to do with X.F?

Comment: What is the purpose of using native `UIAlertView`? I'd like to suggest you to use `Acr.UserDialogs` as shared solution for `Xamarin.Forms`.

Comment: I use Xamarin.Forms I have a customer page and customer's payment page, if  no payment of the customer,gives an UIAlertView. Click the OK button when I want to navigate the back page.

Comment: You could use [shared](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/) solution.

Answer (score 1):

`UIAleartView` does not have specific events for Buttons. 
But, you can access the index of the button pressed from the `UIButtonEventArgs` (ex: `e.ButtonIndex`) verify what button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Xamarin.Forms doesn't have `UIAlertView` class (Inside the PCL project).
You can display alert there by calling asynchronous `DisplayAlert` method inside the `Page` instance. For example:

```
public class PaymentPage
{
    ...

    async void OnNoPaymentMethodDetected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error", "You have no payment method registered", "Okay");
        await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
    }
    ...
}
```

> Note: your Pop Navigation method depends on your Push Navigation method. For instance, if you've used `PushModalAsync(page2)`, then you have to use `PopModalAsync()` in *page2* to move back, otherwise `PopAsync()` will cause an error.

If you want to have similar alert in iOS-specific project, you have to use the next code:

```
var controller = UIAlertController.Create("Error", "No payment method detected", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

controller.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Okay", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, (sender) =>
{
    NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
}));

ShowDetailViewController(controller, null);
```